Did the Corix Family create Gnosis?
in The Legend of Heroes: Trails to Azure we learn that the Croix family were the original caretakers of the Sept-Terrion of Mirage, Demiourgos. but after Demiourgos erased herself the Croix family becomes obsessed with reobtaining the Sept-Terrion of Mirage, creating KeA to become the new Sept-Terrion and the D∴G Cult to look after her until she awoke while the Croix family went into Banking.
According to Joachim's notes, the D∴G Cult used Pleroma Grass as the main ingredient for Gnosis. Zeit also mentioned to Llyod that Pleroma Grass was used by Demiourgos to expand her presence and that it was flowering all over the place in Trails to Azure because of KeA's ascension as a Sept-Terrion.
given Pleroma Grass's connection with Demiourgos and KeA and the cradle she was in was given to the D∴G Cult by the Croix family, did the Corix Family also create Gnosis?
